# Django Template how to fix error "Could not parse the remainder: '|' from '|' "

Tags: python, django, dictionary, templates

```
mydict = {"book1":["user1", "user2", "user3"], 
          "book2":["user1", "user4", "user5"],}
```

I want to check "Does user2 read book1?" in mydict in template, I do the following:

```
{% if "user2" in mydict | get_item: "book1" %}
```

However, i getting an error:

> Could not parse the remainder: '|' from '|'

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is a bit off. You should not place spaces around the pipe character (`|`), and thus write it like:

```
{% if "user2" in mydict|get_item:"book1" %}
```

That being said, if the key itself is fixed, it might make more sense to pass an extra variable like:

```
books1 = mydict['book1']
```

to the template, and render it like:

```
{% if "user2" in books1 %}
```

so without a template filter.

Comment: I want to create a loop for book, example:

` {% for book in books %}
       {% if request.user in mydict|get_item:book.name %}`

How can I do?

Comment: @NguyễnTuấnVũ: yeah sure, then it is not a problem, then the above will likely work. I'm only saying that if you know the key in advance, it makes more sense to put a reference to the corresponding value in the context.

Comment: @NguyễnTuấnVũ: as for the comment, `request.user` is a `User` object, not a `str`ing, so in that case you will need to rewrite the condition to `{% if request.user.username in ... %}` (or if you used another model some other attribute).